# integrate Sothink Video Encoder in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, video

how to Convert all videos to flv format using  Sothink Video Encoder in asp.net c#

Answer (score 1):

If there is a command line version of the tool then you could setup some kind of windows service/web service that will automatically call the command line version and pass the correct arguments which will convert your videos.